# Update Latitude & Longitude values using Javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps-markers

I am working with google maps in rails 3.2.12, I need to update the Latitude and Longitude values through infoWindow for the location created value

If i click on any marker on the map, infowindow will open with location name & two button( "Update" & "Remove") On click on update the current infowindow should close and open otherinfow window latitude and longitude values showing in the text field.

Please find my code below

On click on Update button the below function should call

```
function getlocation(){

            currentprojectid = $('#currentprojectid').val();
            sid = $('#sessionid').val();
            uid = $('#userid').val()
            var locdata = {
                      userid: ,
                      sessionid: sid,
                      command: 'locationupdate',
                      projectid: currentprojectid
                  };

    markersArray.push(marker);
    currentmarker = marker;
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(event){
        infowindow.close()
        infowindow.setContent("<p>LocatioName:&nbsp; <input id="country" type="text" value='+ address +'></p>\
              <p>Longitude:&nbsp;&nbsp;<input id="lat" type="text" value='+ lattitude +'> </p>\
            <p>Lattitude:&nbsp;&nbsp;<input id="long" type="text" value='+ longitude +'> </p>\
            <p><input type="button" value="Save" onclick="saveLocation(currentprojectid)"/
             <input type="button" value="Remove" onclick="removeMarker()"/></p>");
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });


    currentmarker = marker;
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: Gmaps.map.map,
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(lattitude, longitude),
        draggable: true
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are fetching the data from a database then remove the marker by the id of the marker 
try this code..if this help you:

```
<head>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDMM9AqbeqIGxanHcZc9Ce3C9rRSRz6qvI&v=3.exp&libraries=places&sensor=false&amp"></script>
    <script>
        var map;
        var marker;
        var center = new google.maps.LatLng(21.0000,78.0000);
        function initialize(){
        var mapProp = {
          center:center,
          zoom:5,
          mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
          };

        map =  new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap")
          ,mapProp);

        var content = "<input type='button' id='click' value='add marker' />";

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position:center
        });

        marker.setMap(map);


        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

            infowindow.setContent(content);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);


            // currentPopup = null;
        });

     }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="googleMap" style="height:500px; width:550px"></div>

    <script>
        $("body").on("click","#click",function(){
            var mycenter = new google.maps.LatLng(24.0000,78.0000);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position:mycenter
        });

            marker.setMap(map);
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
         infowindow.setContent("am new");
         infowindow.open(map,marker);
        });

    </script>
</body>
```